# How to insert and transform geometry fields in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have a `source` table with a `geometry(Point,27700)` column, and a `target` table with a `geometry(Point,4326)` column.

I am using the following Python code to join the two:

```
q = "SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_AsText(geom), 4326) FROM source WHERE id=%s"
cursor.execute(q, (id)
geom = cursor.fetchone()
if geom:
    query = "INSERT INTO target(geom) VALUES(%s)"
    cursor.execute(query, (geom))
```

However, if I then extract the `target` table using the following command:

```
 ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON out.geojson "PG:host=localhost dbname=mydb" -sql "SELECT * FROM target"
```

The geom fields still look like 27700:

```
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 354151.0, 193500.0 ] } }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use ST_Transform not ST_SetSRID.  ST_SetSRID just changes the srid stamp of a geometry (or adds one if it has known).  ST_Transform actually changes the geometry coordinates from the one stamped on geometry to the desired one.  However the srid has to be known (not 0) for ST_Transform to be used.

```
q = "SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 4326) FROM source WHERE id=%s"
```

If your geometries have no SRID then you have to use both set and transform.

```
q = "SELECT ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom,27700), 4326) FROM source WHERE id=%s"
```